# Plotting a graph for datasets to develop SVM on Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-visualization

I have written the below code that generates two different datasets. I want to plot the graphs X and y but I couldn't find how to draw it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC

std = [[0.5, 0], [0, 0.5]]
X1 = np.vstack((
np.random.multivariate_normal([2, -2], std, size=200),
np.random.multivariate_normal([-2, 2], std, size=200)
))
y1 = np.zeros(X1.shape[0])

X2 = np.vstack((
np.random.multivariate_normal([2, 2], std, size=200),
np.random.multivariate_normal([-2, -2], std, size=200)
))
y2 = np.ones(X2.shape[0])

X = np.vstack((X1, X2))
y = np.hstack((y1, y2))
```

I tried;

```
plt.scatter(X, y) 
plt.show
```

But as you can guess they have given me errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two lines will create a scatter plot that visualizes your data

```
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:,1], c=y)
plt.show()
```